# Which UI Widget should be used for a "back to top" action on a list?

Tags: android, lists, mobile-application, app, listview

I'm designing an android app with a long list, on which I'm implementing a 'back to top' action. My first go-to was a floating action button, but I'm wondering if I can use some other widget or some other kind of interface(action) that is intuitive. I checked out Google's Material Design but there isn't anything specific. Is there some better UI/UX for this function that is usually done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating arrow button pointing "UP" when you pass a certain scroll height seems to be the standard way.

That behaviour is also used quite a lot in chat/messenger apps, especially when there are new messages and you have to scroll down to find them.

If you have long content a back-to-top link can prove useful. However, for normal content, users will usually scroll using the scrollbar and they often scroll at the top to gain access to the menu.

If you want to omit a "back-to-top" button I would suggest making your navigation/header fixed so at any point your users can navigate through the app with ease.

You can read more about ['back to top' and other in-page links on the NN/G website](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/in-page-links/).

Comment: Thanks! I personally feel the nav/header thing isn't very intuitive, so I stuck with the button. I still don't like the way it blocks a part of my screen though(even though I made it more transparent and small, it still feels like it takes over a noticeable part of my screen). I want the user to focus on the list with minimal interference

Comment: It's all up to how long is your content. Users [https://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-attention/](do scroll). However, how do you make things easier for them and offer a pleasant product? If your content is of average length I would say it is ok not to offer a "back-to-top" option.

However, if it is. Perhaps instead of a button you could add a subtle fixed bar at the bottom that takes them back to top past a certain scroll position. Or a link at the end of you text?

Ultimately you know if you need that function and it is up to you to experiment on the best way to approach this.